# Is there a tool available to generate related search terms?

Tags: php, search

I would like to develop basic search functionality for a project I'm working on.  The platform I'm working on is PHP with a combination of MySQL and MongoDB.  I would like to provide users a related search terms list like Google and many other search engines do.  Is there an existing tool (which is easy to incorporate into a PHP application) that given a search string would return a list of possible related searches?  I have done some searching on this subject but can't seem to find anything.

EDIT:
If such a tool doesn't exist, simple but effective implementation ideas would be greatly appreciated as well.  At this time I wouldn't have a large data source for searches that have been made in the system as it is not yet live or being used and a manual mapping would be more than I alone could handle anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Solr: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/